# verify user linux bash

Tags: linux, bash, menu

I'm trying to make an "interactive" very basic menu, to check either

1. user exists
2. get a user UID by typing his login
3. Quit

I have to use loops to find info.

```
 #!/usr/bin/bash 
 getent passwd $user > /dev/null
 read -p "1-check if user exists 
              2-Connaitre l'uid d un utilisateur
              q-Quit": value
if ($value -eq 1 );
then 
read -p "enter username": user 
elif [ $? -eq 0 ]; then 

echo "user exists"
 fi
```

Comment: thanks jonsharpe for fixing my code...apologies

Answer (score 0):

You can use `select`:

```
select value in "check if user exists" "Connaitre l'uid d un utilisateur" "Quit"; do echo $value; done
```